# how to solve the camel looping while processing a file to unmarshalling

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am using camel to process a file, In that 5000 records are there. And each field in a record seperated by delimiter "^".  While unmarshalling, the camel becomes loop because in my file one record contains double quotes("). I removed that and tried, then it is processing fine. How to solve this looping problem in camel?

```
<route id = "corefilemarshalling"> 
<from uri="direct:coreFileMarshalling"/> 
<to uri="bean:droolRecord?method=setFile" /> 
<unmarshal> 
    <csv delimiter="^" useMaps="true"> 
        <header>
            ID
        </header>
        <header>
            NAME
        </header> 
        <header>
            CUSTOMER ID
        </header> 
        <header>
            ADDR1
        </header> 
        <header>
            ADDR2
        </header> 
        <header>
            SALARY
        </header> 
        <header>
            DESIGNATION
        </header>
```

Comment: Can you give an example with code of what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: <route id = "corefilemarshalling">
   <from uri="direct:coreFileMarshalling"/>
   <to uri="bean:droolRecord?method=setFile" />
   <unmarshal>
    <csv delimiter="^" useMaps="true">
     <header>ID</header>
     <header>NAME</header>
     <header>CUSTOMER ID</header>
     <header>ADDR1</header>
     <header>ADDR2</header>
     <header>SALARY</header>
     <header>DESIGNATION</header>

Comment: Perhaps, before unmarshaling, check each row if there is doublequotes. If so, discard that row to some backout queue. Ideally the system sending the data should fix it and resend it rather than Camel "cleaning" the data.

Comment: What version of Camel do you use. And can you show us the row that has this double quote problem?

Comment: I am using camel 2.16 version and the record in a page is

Comment: 0219944443^rajesh             ^456556444^"RAjendernagar, ^jahangeer^10000^tax auditor^